# ListLinePlot for specific range

Tags: plotting, random

I'm trying to plot the following code starting x-axis from 12 and ending on 30, and nos starting on 0, because the first 11 steps have information I dont need. How can I do that?

```
ListLinePlot[
  Table[
    NestList[# + RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[-#/7, 1/4]]&, 0, 30],
    1000]]
```

Answer (score 2):

For illustration purposes, five plots are enough.

```
ListLinePlot[
  Table[
    NestList[# + RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[-#/7, 1/4]] &, 0, 30][[12 ;; -1]],
    5],
  DataRange -> {12, 30}]
```

[image: plot]